# create a shell.sh which anyone can execute which internally runs as root

Tags: php, linux, root

Can I write a shell script which anyone can execute which INTERNALLY switches user (or elevates to root) and then runs those commands without exposing the executing user to root privileges?

Some background: I have a shell script which gets a file from my local network (using smbclient) and then converts and treats said file to a csv ready to import into my MYSQL DB. I can run the file as myself but when I try and execute it thru in PHP exec() or shell_exec() I get permission issues because it's user is www-data.

I've spend a day tring various file permision changes, apending the path environment and even reading up on granting www-data sudo rights (without success) but, rather than all that can I create a file anyone (www-data) can execute and safety perform the commands within (and only the commands within) as my user or sudo?

Comment: No you cannot.  A binary executable can have the `setgid` or `setuid` (or both) bits set, but doing so on a shell script has no effect.  I would fix your script so it is executable by the `www-data` user.

Comment: Oh, and you should post the code you've tried, and exact error messages.  Properly formatted of course.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by editing /etc/sudoers

```
sudoedit /etc/sudoers
```

add this line

```
Cmnd_Alias YOUR_CMD_ALIAS= /path/yourShellScript

[User's name] ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: YOUR_CMD_ALIAS
```

then execute your code with sudo

```
sudo /path/yourShellScript
```